# How to change some symbols (e.g. "space") to other symbol in Bash/shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, text

I have some output from

```
ps -ef | grep apache
```

I need to change all spaces in that output to '@' symbol
Is it possible to use some bash script for this?
Thanks

Comment: Why? I don't mean to be flip; it's just that it seems you want to pass the result to another command where the spaces will cause problems, and there may be a better approach than working with the output of `ps` in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`tr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29):

```
ps -ef | grep apache | tr ' ' @
```

Answer (score 4):

use `tr`:

```
$ echo 'foo bar baz' | tr ' ' '@'
foo@bar@baz
```

([documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr))

Answer (score 3):

Basic sed command:

```
ps -ef | grep apache | sed 's/ /@/g'
```

`sed 's/text/new text/g'` looks for "text" and replaces it with "new text".

In case you want to replace more characters, for example replace all spaces and `_` with `@`: (thanks [Adrian Frühwirth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/612462/adrian-fruhwirth)):

```
ps -ef | grep apache | sed 's/[_ ]/@/g'
```

Comment: Why not use a character class, e.g. `sed 's/[ _]/@/g'` instead?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth thanks, I didn't know we could do such thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can can skip the extra `grep` if you use `awk`:

```
ps -ef | awk '/apache/{gsub(/ /,"@");print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple space characters to be replaced with only one `@` symbol, you can use `-s` flag with `tr`:

```
ps -ef | grep apache | tr -s ' ' '@'
```

or this `sed` solution:

```
ps -ef | grep apache | sed -r 's/ +/@/g'
```